How to tell if a markov chain will visit all states before absorption?
I have this Markov Chain with an absorbing state:
$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
0.3 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.1 \\
0.2 & 0.3 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.1 \\
0.2 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.2 & 0.1 \\
0.2 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

I am wondering about the following question. Suppose we start in State 1:

What percent of the time can we expect the Markov Chain to visit all states (at least once) before being absorbed?
On average, how long will this take?

I am not sure how to analyze this mathematically, so I simulated it:

But how could I have analyzed this mathematically without simulation?

I'm sure there's a more general technique, but because of the symmetry here, I think the probability of visiting all five states should be $\frac67 \cdot \frac45 \frac23 = \frac{16}{35}$. Does that match your simulation?

Similarly, the expected time to complete a visit to all states (including the absorption state) should be $\frac{10}{7}+\frac{10}{5}+\frac{10}{3}+\frac{10}{1} = \frac{352}{21}$. Does that match?

I'll write up an answer shortly if no one has done it by the time I get a chance.

would really appreciate it! :)

There is, as the other answer indicates, a more general approach in which you track not only the current state but which states you've already visited. For small systems such as the one you're examining, this is tractable, but the state bookkeeping quickly gets tedious. I don't know offhand if there's a way to extract the probability of a complete tour, the expected time to complete the tour, etc., without solving the system in all details.
For this particular system, however, we can leverage the symmetries in the probability transitions. We'll assume, naturally, that we don't start in state $S_5$.

Whichever of the four remaining states we start in, since the probability of staying put is $3/10$, the probability of leaving is $7/10$ and the average time taken to exit that one state is $10/7$. At the moment we leave, the probability of being absorbed is $1/7$ and the probability of moving to any other new state is $6/7$.

Now, at each turn, the probability of either staying put or moving to the other state we've already visited is $5/10$, so the probability of leaving both states is $5/10$ and the average time taken to do so is $10/5$. At that moment, the probability of being absorbed is $1/5$ and the probability of moving to either new state is $4/5$.

At this point, we've now visited three states. The probability of either staying put or moving to one of the other states we've already visited is $7/10$, so the probability of leaving all three states is $3/10$ and the average time taken to do so is $10/3$. When we leave, the probability of being absorbed is $1/3$ and the probability of moving to either new states is $2/3$.

Finally, now we've visited all four non-absorbing states. We are guaranteed to complete the tour. The probability at each turn of reaching the absorbing state is $1/10$, so the average time taken to do so is $10/1$.


Therefore, the probability of completing the tour is
\begin{align}
P(\text{complete tour}) & = \frac67 \times \frac45 \times \frac23 \\
                        & = \frac{16}{35} \approx 0.45714
\end{align}
and the expected time taken to do so is
\begin{align}
E(\text{time for complete tour})
    & = \frac{10}{7} + \frac{10}{5} + \frac{10}{3} + \frac{10}{1} \\
    & = \frac{352}{21} \approx 16.762
\end{align}
with a standard deviation of
\begin{align}
\sigma
    & = \sqrt{\frac{30}{49}+\frac{50}{25}+\frac{70}{9}+\frac{90}{1}} \\
    & = \sqrt{\frac{1106800}{11025}} \\
    & = \frac{4}{21}\sqrt{2767} \approx 10.019  
\end{align}
which would correspond to an interquartile distance of about $13.5$ or so.

If we don't achieve a complete tour, the expected time to be absorbed is
\begin{align}
E(\text{time for incomplete tour})
    & = \frac{\frac17\left(\frac{10}{7}\right)
      + \frac67\frac15\left(\frac{10}{7}+\frac{10}{5}\right)
      + \frac67\frac45\frac13\left(\frac{10}{7}+\frac{10}{5}
                                  +\frac{10}{3}\right)}
        {\frac17+\frac67\frac15+\frac67\frac45\frac13} \\
    & = \frac{1718}{399} \approx 4.3058
\end{align}
Thanks to Daniel Mathias in the comments for catching an error here, as well as providing a much more succinct route to the correct answer!

Simulation agrees with your complete tour results, but suggests the expected time for an incomplete tour is $\approx 4.305$

@DanielMathias: OK, thanks, that's the part I was least sure about, so let me think about it some more!

$P(\text{complete})\times E(\text{complete}) + P(\text{incomplete})\times E(\text{incomplete})=10$ gives us $E(\text{incomplete})=\frac{1718}{399}\approx 4.30576$

@DanielMathias: Yeah, I just arrived at the same answer more directly, but that line of reasoning is faster.

thank you everyone! I wonder - what is the probability distribution of this time?

@user_436830: Offhand, I can't think of any quick way of doing it. I'd probably go by way of the generating function for the incomplete tour times. I don't think you can back into it the way Daniel Mathias did for the expected time.

In principle, you have to consider a new Markov chain $(S_n,X_n)$ where $S_n$  is a subset of the set $E$ of the states of the chain $(X_n)$. The set $S_n$ contains $X_n$. The new chain  has the following transition rule $S_{n+1}=S_n\cup\{X_{n+1}\}$ if $X_{n+1}\notin S_n$ and $S_{n+1}=S_n$ if $X_{n+1}\in S_n.$ If $d=|E|$ is very small (say with 3 or 4 elements) the transition matrix is tractable with $2^{d-1}\times d$ elements. If $a$ is the unique absorbing state, you look for reaching the state  $(E,a)$ for the new chain.

I think this can be further simplified given the simmetry. The new Markov chain states $S_n$ can just be the number of states already visited. You don't care which ones they were; if you visited already two states, it doesn't matter whether they were 1 and 2 or 1 and 3; the probability of transitioning to a non visited state or being absorbed is the same.
